# jGrowl: How can I limit my interface to one message at a time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, message-queue, messaging, jgrowl

Given: I load a queue of messages at page load.

> With jGrowl, how can I display each message, one message at a time, in a drip-like fashion?

Answer (score 8):

I needed to do this for a project, a few months ago. If you use the pooling feature, available in the latest jGrowl (1.2.0 as of this writing), you can simply write:

```
$.jGrowl.defaults.pool = 1;
```

That way, you can load all of them at the same time, jGrowl will take care of only showing one at a time. When a message closes, jGrowl will automatically display the next one.

I hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

$.jGrowl.defaults.pool == 0;

if ( $(this.element).find('div.jGrowl-notification:parent').size() < 0 ) {

Currently working on site notifications, I couldn't find a way to show one at a time until I found this page. 
Thanks Bruno! You saved me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you specify the time interval that a message is displayed for (at maximum), you could simply use a JS *setTimeout* to loop through an array at the same interval, creating a new message.

Alternatively, jGrowl can take a function(e,m,o) as its *close* parameter, and it will use it as a callback whenever a message is closed. In this function, create a new message from your queue and you should be set. See documentation [here](http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html).