# close previous jGrowl notifications before showing a new one

Tags: jquery, notifications, jgrowl

I have a simple app that executes `$.jGrowl("loading");`.  Then the data is displayed `$.jGrowl("blah blah blah data goes here");` after crunching data which can take 1 -5 seconds.

I've seen a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327527/jgrowl-how-can-i-limit-my-interface-to-one-message-at-a-time) that mentions using the default.pool to only display one message at a time.  The format I want is:

- Show box 1
- crunch data
- close box 1
- show box 2

Is there a jGrowl function that can be initiated to close all notifications?

*UPDATE*
according to the source example you can do the folowing
`$('#loading').jGrowl('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />');`
then call to close it
`$('#loading').jGrowl('shutdown');`
`<div id="loading" class="top-right"></div>`
that does hide the loading growl, however it also hide subsequent notifications in that region.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#loadinggrowl').jGrowl('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />');
$.jGrowl('content here');
document.getElementById('loadinggrowl').style.display = "none";

<body><div id="loading" class="top-right"></div></body>
```

Line 3 above hides the loadinggrowl div after loading the content.

this may not be the best way, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all notification with `$(".jGrowl-notification").each`, trigger the close fonction with `.trigger('jGrowl.beforeClose')`, and create your new growl, like below :

```
$(".jGrowl-notification").each(function () {
    if ($(this).data("jGrowl") !== undefined && $(this).data("jGrowl").created !== undefined) {
        $(this).data("jGrowl").trigger('jGrowl.beforeClose');
    }
});
$.jGrowl("NEW MESSAGE");
```